# Target class [MessagesController] does not exist

Tags: laravel-8

I am running `php artisan route:list` then it gives me an error which is-- **Target class [MessagesController] does not exist.**

at **vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879**

But I don't have any controller named MessagesController. I searched in my vs code default search bar but nothing comes up. I am using laravel 8

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: If you have copied your project and have not installed it fresh check if you have FILE named MessagesController, since file names will not pop up in the VSCode search

Comment: yeah I deleted them but still showing the error